# How does one keep track of many objects in OO design?

Tags: oop

I'm struggling with an issue regarding basic object-oriented design that I don't really have the vocabulary to describe. I'm a first-year computer systems student, so my software development education so far is focused on the very basics.

In a large OO project, like for instance a role-playing game, you can end up with many objects whose names are not known at compile time. In a game example, you might have a database file containing details of different enemy encounters. A particular encounter might have the player face three goblin warriors and a troll berserker. These different enemies might all be instances of class Combatant, with different creation arguments specifying their powers and equipment.

However, when instantiating these objects, what names do we give them? Stated differently: I use Python, and when you instantiate an object, you need to give it an identifying name in order to refer to it later; but how can I name a thing if the variable name itself is not literally typed into my code?

```
next_combatant = load_from_file()

??? = Combatant(next_combatant)
```

In other words, what do I put in place of the ??? above?

The solution I'm currently using is to use lists (arrays), appending each new object to the list. This way each object does not strictly have a name in the sense of 'goblin_003', but I can refer to objects by using indices of the list, and I can also do other nice things like count how many enemies there are, etc.

My question, then: is this how it is handled in industry? Do programmers typically use arrays to keep all their objects organised? Or is there some clever trick that allows me to retrieve a variable name from file?

(I realise this question is poorly worded, so if anyone needs clarification, just ask.)

EDIT: Is there a name for using collections in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Collections serve this purpose well enough. With many collections, you don't need to specify an identifier of a stored item. However, if you would like to, a dictionary is a way to go. I don't know much about python, but there should be some collection where you specify a key and a value for an item you want to store in it.

Just imagine that you are to create millions of warriors in one game. It would not made a sense to have warrior_999999 and warrior_1000000.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, you don't have variable names for all monsters and objects in your game or in other software where you need dynamic content. And you don't need any variable names really.

But what is correct way to store those objects depends on your needs, what you wanna do with them and what is purpose of your objects. You can use Arrays, Lists, Trees and what ever, what just makes sense in your use case.

If you need to identify specific dynamic object / monster in your game/software, add identifier variable to your object.

---

Identifier variable in your object can be just integer value. But you have to keep it so that you don't have two objects with same value.

Example, if you have 3 monster objects in array and monster object has `int id;` variable.

- Monster1, id = 1
- Monster2, id = 2
- Monster3, id = 3... and so on.

In OpenGL, if you use picking, good identifier is RGBA value:

- Monster1, id = RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1);
- Monster2, id = RGBA(0, 0, 0, 2);
- Monster256, id = RGBA(0, 0, 1, 0); and so on.

What is right identifier, depends again on your needs.

Comment: Could you clarify your statement about identifier variables? I don't understand what you mean by that. Otherwise, thanks.

Comment: OK, so you mean just adding some property to the class to allow us to uniquely identify instances? Cool.

Comment: @henrebotha Yes, add unique property value if you need to identify instances.